How to understand that there is a photo in the buffer JavaScript
I want to determine that when I click on the Print Screen button on  keyboard, is it written to the console whether it’s a image or not? Needs use buffer like
const checkHaveImageInClipboar = async () => {
        try {
            const clipboardItems = await window.navigator.clipboard.read();
            return clipboardItems[0].types.some(type => /image/.test(type));
        } catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    };

It is on the button on the keyboard, and not on the button in the DOM . Because there may be a situation where you clicked on the screenshot on the keyboard, but the screen didn’t work, and I just want to check
if there is a photo in the buffer, then output 'photo', otherwise output 'not photo' . Please help me

AFAIK PrintScreen works outside of the browser.

@evolutionxbox, i use
window.addEventListener('keyup', event => { if (event.keyCode === 44 (it's keyCode for Screen)

What does not work with your approach?

Yes, you'll detect the keypress but that doesn't necessarily put something in the clipboard. Even if a screenshot is taken. On my computer, I get the screenshot in another piece of software (Greenshot) but not in the copy buffer. But conversely, if somebody already had an image in their clipboard and print screen "didn't work", then your code would get a false positive.

It's notable, that Clipboard stores data in multiple different formats, exact formats depend on the application copying data. Just for an example: Excel stores a copied selection as a png image as well as HTML among other formats.
